# Get value from a different type of array

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array

```
Array
(
    [activity] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [action] => open
                    [timestamp] => 2019-08-02T21:34:03+00:00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [action] => open
                    [timestamp] => 2019-08-02T20:27:54+00:00
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [action] => click
                    [timestamp] => 2019-08-02T20:27:54+00:00
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [action] => open
                    [timestamp] => 2019-08-02T20:26:43+00:00
                )
    )
)
```

I want to count the total number of action which has action=open. So the result will be 3

Comment: where are your trials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [array-column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array-count-values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) as:

```
$actions = array_column($arr['activity'], 'action');
$cnts = array_count_values($actions );
```

Now just print the 'open` as:

```
echo $cnts['open'];
```

You can also do simple loop as:

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach($arr['activity'] as $e) {
    if ($e['action'] == 'open') $cnt++;
    if ($cnt == 1) echo "First open at: " . $e['timestamp']; // print the date of the first open action
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @dWinder. Can I get the date of the first activity which has action is open. action=>open can be any position? Thanks